# What is this value in a vtable output from Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, vtable

Consider the following code:

```
class base {
 public:
   base() = default;
   virtual int foo() { return 0; }
};

class derived : public base {
 public:
   derived() = default;
   virtual int foo() { return 1;}
};
```

Compiling this with Clang 3.3 I get the following output for the vtable:

```
__ZTV7derived:
.long   0        <--- what is this?
.long   __ZTI7derived
.long   __ZN7derived3fooEv
```

If I add the switch `-fno-rtti` I get this:

```
__ZTV7derived:
.long   0        <--- what is this?
.long   0        <--- type info removed by -fno-rtti
.long   __ZN7derived3fooEv
```

Which makes sense since the TypeInfo is now invalid, but what is the first `.long 0` referring to?  Also, why doesn't `-fno-rtti` remove the type info altogether rather than just zero-ing it?  I'm considering writing a pass to do this manually, but I'd like to know the implications of it first (I'm squeezing bytes out of an embedded platform)

Comment: @MM. Thanks, that looks like that's it!  Though I'm still curious what happens if I remove this info manually (since -fno-rtti doesn't completely remove it)

Comment: The second-entry is zeroed-out for binary compatibility. You could link with a rtti-enabled library from a no-rtti program for example.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan I see, that makes sense.  If I'm doing this as a "whole program" optimization, I'd be safe then?  I already strictly forbid `dynamic_cast` and multiple inheritance.

Comment: @SamCristall. Can't say anything further than that. Not sure what the compiler does with the rest of that information. Does it assume that same offset for virtual function lookup ? If it does you would run into a whole new bunch of problems. You'd need intricate knowledge of what the compiler does.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan I'll have to dig into it to check on that, I was mostly just concerned with the C++ language implications of cutting this info out.  Thanks for your help!